# How to draw a line on panel? It is not showing up

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, line, panel

I have a `Panel` called `panel1` and I am trying to draw a line on my `panel1` using this code:

```
var g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
var p = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

var point1 = new Point(234,118);
var point2 = new Point(293,228);

g.DrawLine(p, point1, point2);
```

But nothing is showing up. Any ideas? This is in a windows form.

Comment: Do you have this in the Paint() event?

Comment: I have it in the constructor

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Handle the Panel's [Paint event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx) and put it in there. What's happening is that it's being drawn once in the constructor but then being drawn over in the `Paint` event everytime it's called.

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    using(Graphics g = e.Graphics)
    {
       var p = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);
       var point1 = new Point(234,118);
       var point2 = new Point(293,228);
       g.DrawLine(p, point1, point2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Other way of seeing the line is to create a button and draw your line in the OnClick Method of the button like so:  private void btnDraw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics dc = drawingArea.CreateGraphics();
            Pen BlackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);

            dc.DrawLine(BlackPen, 0, 0, 200, 200);


            BlackPen.Dispose();
            dc.Dispose();
        }

Answer (score 3):

Put it in some event after the form has been created and shown on the screen and it should work fine.

It's best to put it in the Paint event, as keyboardP stated, but it will not show up if called before the form is shown on the screen.

To test this you can add a button and add the code to the click event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics())
    {
        g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Back, 3), new Point(234,118), new Point(293,228));
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be best to lead by example and wrap that in a `using` statement? :)

Comment: Tried changing the g definition, nothing happened

Comment: Changed my answer. Not the issue I though it was.

Answer (score 0):

To see your drawing - you can simply make a button with a Click Event and draw when the button is clicked. For example:

```
private void btnDraw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Graphics dc = drawingArea.CreateGraphics();
    Pen BlackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
    dc.DrawLine(BlackPen, 0, 0, 200, 200);

    BlackPen.Dispose();
    dc.Dispose();
}
```

Oh, and by the way "drawingArea" is the (Name) of either a PictureBox or Panel you have added to your form (to draw in it).

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the other answers and still your drawings are not showing up try removing all controls from the control that is being drawn to. The other controls may be covering whatever you are trying to draw.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(
            (object sender1, PaintEventArgs e1) => {
                var p = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);
                var point1 = new Point(234, 118);
                var point2 = new Point(293, 228);
                e1.Graphics.DrawLine(p, point1, point2);
            }
        );
        
        panel1.Invalidate();
        
    }
```