# Draw line on a Krypton Panel?

Tags: .net, vb.net, gdi+, paint, krypton-toolkit

I would like to draw a line on the middle of a Krypton Toolkit Panel control but the line is not drawn.

I've tried both soultions here: [draw line on panel not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943387/draw-line-on-panel-not-showing-up)

And this:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub KryptonPanel1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) _
Handles KryptonPanel1.Paint

    Using p As New Pen(Brushes.YellowGreen)
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, sender.Width \ 2, 0, sender.Width \ 2, sender.Bottom)
    End Using

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Have you placed a breakpoint on the method to see if the code is actually getting executed?

Comment: Done, is not executed, what I'm missing?, I've tried to enable/disable some suspiciouos  control properties but the method is still not executed

Comment: When did the object type get properties like `.Width` and `.Bottom`?

Comment: Are you assigning the `KryptonPanel1_Paint` event handler programmatically or via the designer?

Comment: via the designer, I just created a new project to test this, the full code is only the above code

Comment: Sorry, I saw your comment `Done, is not executed` too late:/

Comment: Was the `KryptonPanel1_Paint` method auto generated by the designer?

Comment: does it need an OwnerDraw property or similar set?

Comment: @Bryan Roth yes I clicked on the event grid to autogenerate the method

Comment: @Plutonix it has not an ownerdraw property, it has a "draw" property to enable drawing the background but I toggled that property and still can't draw the line

Comment: @ElektroStudios If possible, create a custom class inherited from `Krypton Panel`. Override the `OnPaint` method and debug. If not you have always `WndProc` and `WM_PAINT`.

Comment: As long as they did not seal the class - `NotInheritable`

Comment: @DonA Yup, that's why i wrote `If possible` ;) Anyway, I hope it's not sealed, or this might be a lost case.

Comment: Is the code you posted the extent of your `Form1` class? Does your form get loaded?

Comment: @Bryan Roth The code is as is only that piece of code that I've posted, of course the form loads and displays and the panel begins painted/designed, but not my intention of draw a line, thanks for comment

Comment: @ElektroStudios Are you handling the correct event? Have you tried handling other `KryptonPanel` events?

Comment: @Bryan Roth I think yes because I don't see any other similar Painting Event

Comment: @ElektroStudios Have you tried handling any other type of event exposed by the `KryptonPanel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point, I think it's safe to conclude that the `Krypton Toolkit Panel` do not have the control style `UserPaint`.

> "If true, the control paints itself rather than the operating system doing so. **If false, the Paint event is not raised.** This style only applies to classes derived from Control." [- MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlstyles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If possible, you can try one of the following options.

Start by creating a custom control derived from `Krypton Toolkit Panel`.

**Option 1**

Append the flag in the constructor. (This will probably break the custom drawings in base class)

```
Public Sub New()
    MyBase.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)
End Sub
```

**Option 2**

Override `WndProc`.

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    Try
        If ((m.Msg = WM_PAINT) OrElse (m.Msg = WM_ERASEBKGND)) Then
            Using g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics()
                Me.OnPaint(New PaintEventArgs(g, Me.ClientRectangle))
            End Using
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Try
End Sub

Const WM_PAINT As Integer = 15
Const WM_ERASEBKGND As Integer = 20
```